# View source in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Does anybody know of a tool where I can inspect the source code of a site in Apple's iOS Simulator? Something like Firebug or the Chrome Developer Tools for this would be great, and I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> The old, previous answers have been deleted as they contained obsolete information.

Using at least Xcode 4 and Safari 6, open up a web view in the iPhone Simulator, then switch to the desktop Safari. In Safari's Develop menu (you have to enable it in the Preferences), you'll find an "iPad Simulator" menu that allows you to open up the Safari Web Inspector for the pages open in the simulator!

Comment: "then switch to" meaning the Desktop version of Safari. (clarification just in case) This is awesome!! I love Apples developers!

Comment: The Developer Tools / Web Inspector window in Safari Technology Preview 110 shows me the DOM, but it doesn't show me the original rendered web-page source HTML, which is what I need (as far as I can tell, the only way to see it is by reloading the page and capturing it in the Network tab, but this means I can't view the rendered source for a page that's already loaded).