# Not Programming : How to install firebug lite in iPad simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, firebug-lite

I am trying to install firebug lite in my iPad simulator but i could not find out ,how to do this?

Can any one know how to do this?

I am currently using XCode-4.2, iOS Simulator-5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog post](http://www.jamagination.com/jeff/blog/2011/01/19/getting-firebug-lite-working-iphone-simulator-or-how-add-bookmark-safari-iphone) details a method for creating a [Firebug Lite bookmarklet](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable) for iOS Simulator.

Other options for remote inspection include:

- [iWebInspector](http://www.iwebinspector.com/) is a stand alone application that provides a Firebug-like interface for iOS Simulator. I got it working with iOS simulator 5.1
- <s>Bugaboo. (http://bugabooapp.com/)</s>
- <s>[Adobe Shadow](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/)</s> (now [Adobe Edge Inspect](http://www.adobe.com/products/edge-inspect.html)). Description from the website:

  > Adobe® Shadow is a new inspection and preview tool that allows
  >   front-end web developers and designers to work faster and more
  >   efficiently by streamlining the preview process, making it easier to
  >   customize websites for mobile devices.
- [This Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191037/view-source-in-ios-simulator) may also be relevant.